# Optimal MTU settings ADSL for PPPoE over ATM/LLC

Tags: cisco, mtu

Is 1446 optimal for PPPoE over ATM/LLC as [this forum post](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/25798) describes?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum MTU you can expect that all network nodes will allow is 1500, so calculate whatever additional overhead there is and subtract that from 1500.  In this case it appears to be 54 bytes so yes 1446 is fine.

If set too high, you will know - noticeable degradation in performance due to inevitable fragmentation.